# Error Loading Extension Could not load extension from 'C:\..\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6312_32763\internal'. Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-automation-extension

When am running my webdriver script, am getting a confirmation dialog box with below message:

> Error Loading Extension
>
> Could not load extension from 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6312_32763\internal'. Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator.
>
> Would you like to retry?
>
> Yes No

Clicking "yes" lets the tests run.

I am not sure why am I getting this dialog box prompted,

I've tried the mentioned workarounds below but neither of them are working:

1. Replaced chrome driver with latest version.
2. Added below code in my script:

   ```
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.addArguments("no-sandbox");
   options.addArguments("disable-extensions");
   driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
   ```

Below is my Test method:

```
public void Login() throws IOException{
    test = extent.startTest("Login");
    signInPage = new SignInPage(driver);
    signInPage.enterMailId();   
    String screenShotPath = GetScreenShot.capture(driver, "enterMailId");
    test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Email id is entered successfully: " + test.addScreenCapture(screenShotPath));
    signInPage.enterpwd();
    //test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Password is entered successfully");
    screenShotPath = GetScreenShot.capture(driver, "enterpwd");
    test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Password is entered successfully: " + test.addScreenCapture(screenShotPath));
    signInPage.clickOnLogin();
    test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "User logged in successfully");
}
```

Below is the method which invoke the browser:

```
private  void initChromeBrowser(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", userdir +"\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("test-type");
    options.addArguments("no-sandbox");
    //Fix for cannot get automation extension
    options.addArguments("disable-extensions");
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");         
    options.addArguments("disable-plugins");
    options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info"); 
    options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
    options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    launchApp();
}
```

Could there be anything else that I should incorporate in my script to prevent the dialog box.

Comment: Which version of Selenium, Driver & Browser are you using? What are your testing steps? What worked for you? Show code. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 22):

You can set the `useAutomationExtension` capability to false.

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

This capability will help to not load Chrome Automation extension. Due to which, *"Failed to load extension"* popup would not appear.

But please note you will not be able to perform any window resizing/positioning operations without the Chrome automation extension.

Hope this helps!

Source : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1749

Comment: Where do we add this code?  There is no C# or Java code in my .side file

Comment: If someone stumbles upon this looking for WebdriverIO config then you can make this change in the `capabilities` section in the `wdio.conf.js` :
`browserName: 'chrome',
 'goog:chromeOptions':  {"useAutomationExtension": false},`

Comment: This answer works for NightwatchJS as well. In your `nightwatch.json` config file, do:
`{"test_settings":{"default":{"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","goog:chromeOptions":{"useAutomationExtension":false}}}}}`

Answer (score 9):

This error message...

> Error Loading Extension
>
> Could not load extension from 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6312_32763\internal'. Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator.
>
> Would you like to retry?
>
> Yes No

...implies that an extension was not been loaded as it was disabled by the administrator.

As per [Issue 1749: Failed to load extention from: ... Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1749) *ChromeDriver* uses *Chrome automation extension* for automating various functions like window sizing, window positioning, etc.

The **Failed to load extension..** popup means that this extension has not been loaded. If you manually close the popup, browser will act normally and *ChromeDriver* commands will continue to work as expected. But in this case if you try executing window resizing or window re-positioning commands, it will throw an error as **`unknown error: cannot get automation extension`**.

Till *ChromeDriver v2.28* whenever an organizations admin policy forbidden extensions, to bypass the restriction users have used the argument `disable-extensions` as follows:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

and it worked perfecto.

*ChromeDriver v2.28* onwards, whenever `disable-extensions` flag is passed by test, *ChromeDriver* implicitly passes **`disable-extensions-except`** flag which in turn loads *Chrome automation extension*. This extension helps Chromedriver to perform window sizing and window re-positioning operations.

So, if your organizational admin policy blocks extensions, display of popup **Failed to load extension from: ... Loading of unpacked extensions** is an expected behavior.

This issue had a dependency on [Selenium support for headless](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604324).

As an alternative, you can set the **`useAutomationExtension`** capability to `false` as follows:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

This capability inturn will help to not load *Chrome Automation extension* and **`Failed to load extension`** popup would not appear. But you will not be able to perform any window resizing/positioning operations without the *Chrome automation extension*.

Now, [Selenium support for headless](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604324) being resolved *ChromeDriver* will no longer require this extension and you shouldn't have seen this error/popup.

### Solution

The simplest solution would be to use the latest version of *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome* combination among either of the following:

- If you are using **Chrome version 73**, please download **`ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.20`**
- If you are using **Chrome version 72**, please download **`ChromeDriver 2.46`** or **`ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69`**
- If you are using **Chrome version 71**, please download **`ChromeDriver 2.46`** or **`ChromeDriver 71.0.3578.137`**
- For older version of Chrome, please see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796818/webdriverexception-message-service-usr-lib-chromium-browser-chromedriver-unex/49799791#49799791).

### Alternative

Some other alternatives are:

- Add the *Registry Key* `ExtensionInstallWhitelist` to whitelist
- Remove the *Registry Key* `ExtensionInstallBlacklist` containing a string key **1** with value **`*`**

Comment: Remove the Registry Key ExtensionInstallBlacklist containing a string key 1 with value *, worked! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this same issue after upgrading to ChromeDriver v2.29. I have Chrome v58.0. It looks like an open issue:  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=639#c26

Depending on your versions, YMMV, in my case, I had to downgrade to ChromeDriver v2.27.

Comment: Thank you, downgrading to v2.27 resolved my issue, but now am encountered with below error:

`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension

from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html`

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 5):

If you go to `chrome://version/` you can see under the Command:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-extensions --disable-extensions-except="C:\Users\Inno3\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir80288_6333\internal" --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-automation --enable-logging --force-fieldtrials=SiteIsolationExtensions/Control --ignore-certificate-errors --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12354 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --start-maximized --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Users\Inno3\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir80288_30914" --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end data:,`

This is why it throw error, I don't know why it give error, maybe user policy or Chrome updates?

`--disable-extensions-except="C:\Users\Inno3\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir80288_6333\internal"`

I believe the argument is added by Selenium, you need the following command to tell selenium to not add it.

In C#:

```
chromeOptions = OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
river = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
launchApp();
```

In Java:

```
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false)
```

Comment: this worked like a charm! Thanks for providing examples in both C# and Java, as some of these answers don't apply for me.

Comment: Yep - for C# the above "chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);" was all I needed, other suggestions would not work in the OpenQA.Selenium scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```html
//Set the system property for chrome browser location
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Global.sChromeDriverPath);
    //Set the Chrome capabilities
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
       options.addArguments("test-type");
       options.addArguments("start-maximized");
       options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");
       options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info");
       options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
       options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
       options.addArguments("--enable-automation");
       options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
       options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
       options.addArguments("disable-extensions");
       options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
       Global.driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: By using above code you can disable pop-up and also lunch chrome driver successfully in selenium Automation                                                            Chrome driver version -    ChromeDriver 2.34                                        Chrome Browser  version -  63.0.39

Answer (score 1):

Below code is working fine for me chrome driver 2.41 and browser version 68.0.3440.84

```
public class patCheck {

  WebDriver driver;

  @Test
  public void f() {

      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\shirish.nagar\\Work\\Selenium\\Web\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");

      ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
      options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
      driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.get("https://www.google.com");
  }
}
```

It successfully invokes the chrome browser without any pop-up of "loading unpacked extension disabled by administrator"

Answer (score 1):

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");

    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

On my company we have a GPO that block all extensions on chrome with the [ExtensionInstallBacklist](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallBlacklist).
So to avoid this we change the blocked extentensions registry key from * (all) to a random value (foobar).

To do that you can create a .reg file with this content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallBlacklist]
"1"="lala"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bunch of things like removing the * entry of Chrome blacklist in Windows registry (which is a painful hack because it will be reversed back couple times a week by the company group policy). I finally came up with the working solution. With the following code, the "error loading extension" pop up isn't showing up any more.

```
${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --start-maximized
Call Method    ${options}    add_experimental_option  useAutomationExtension  ${False}
Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me:

Set useAutomationExtension as false

```
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
```

Fulll code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    options.merge(capabilities);
    options.addArguments("--test-type");
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");
    options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info");
    options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
    options.addArguments("--enable-automation");
    options.addArguments("disable-extensions");
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

This below code works for me with the addition of  - options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false) :
...

- System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver path");
- ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
- options.addArguments("test-type");
- options.addArguments("start-maximized");
- options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");
- options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info");
- options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
- options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
- options.addArguments("--enable-automation");
- options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
- options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
- options.addArguments("disable-extensions");
- options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
- driver.new ChromeDriver(options);
- driver.get(ur url);