# What is replica of this java code "setExperimentalOption" in ruby to open chrome browser with 'useAutomationExtension' as false

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, watir

The below java code works fine in my machine to disable automation extension.
How I can write a replica of this code in ruby

Java

```
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
```

In Watir Ruby
this code doesn't work

```
Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, :switches => %w[--disable-popup-blocking  --disable-extensions --disable-infobars] )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try passing it as a raw option:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {options: {'useAutomationExtension' => false}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass them along with `args:` See the update of `Watir 6.6`: http://watir.com/watir-6-6/
In short:

```
Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {args: %w[--disable-popup-blocking  --disable-extensions --disable-infobars]}
```

This is how I like to start the browser keeping all options variable.

```
browser_name = ENV['BROWSER'] || 'chrome'
settings = {}
if ENV['DEVICE'] == 'remote'
  settings[:url] = 'http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub/'
end

if browser_name == 'chrome'
  args = ['--ignore-certificate-errors', '--disable-popup-blocking', '--disable-translate', '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream', '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream']
  settings[:options] = {args: args}
end

Watir::Browser.new browser_name.to_sym, settings
```

Comment: I used the code you provided but I am getting the below pop up everytime the scrip open the browser.How I can avoid showing this pop up."Failed to load extension from :C:\users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir14148_503\internal.Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator".

Comment: settings = {}
                                                                                                       
 args = ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-notifications', '--disable-infobars','--disable-extensions','--disable-popup-blocking']
                                                                                    settings[:options] = {args: args}
                                                                               
Watir::Browser.new :chrome, settings

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: This article goes into that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571119/loading-of-unpacked-extensions-is-disabled-by-the-administrator?rq=1
To me it seems that your laptop is moderated by somenoe else, causing you not to be allowed to start the browser with these capabilities.

Comment: Thank You.I have tried all possibility.I can only ask the IT team to lookinto the installation of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause which is not allowing the script to run.

I navigated to below path in "regedit" and deleted the "ExtensionInstallBlacklist" folder but this is a temporary solution the registry will be auto created in some time.

Path:
“HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallBlacklist”