# Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by administrator

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and Chrome. As soon as I try to open automatically a webpage I get the error:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akgaJ.jpg)

There are some answers on stackexchange on how to solve this issue in Java/C++ but I could not find any relating to Python.
See for example [Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571119/loading-of-unpacked-extensions-is-disabled-by-the-administrator)

Do someone knows how to fix this problem in python?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a lot of work on this issue I finally came up with a solution. By looking at the responses on C# and Java I managed to apply same procedure to Selenium in python.

As described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571119/loading-of-unpacked-extensions-is-disabled-by-the-administrator) you need to somehow set the attribute of `useAutomationExtension` to `False`.

Here is what I did:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions, desired_capabilities=chromeOptions.to_capabilities())
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

The code above simply creates ChromeOptions class and sets the attribute to false. The you run chrome driver with those options.

This solved my case. I hope it helps.

Comment: on ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68 and chrome 76.0.3809.100 the `useAutomationExtension` option seems to take no effect any more. It worked until versions 75.x.y.z

Comment: ~grrr does anybody know how to do this from version 76 onward?