# Robot Framework : Selenium Library : Handling popups from Chrome Browser

Tags: robotframework

I am using the following configuration at my workplace. When I run the following code on my personal laptop it works fine. But on my work laptop, I get this popup. How can I handle this in robotframework?

Python : 2.7.15
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.2.0
robotframework==3.0.4

Chrome browser : 68.0.3440.106
Chrome Webdriver : v2.41

I get the following alert. When I run 
`Open Browser  ${url}  chrome`   # Happens to every url, so I think it's a browser/driver and the setup on my work laptop.

If I manually click the OK button then the test continues as intended

I did explore the following keywords in Selenium Library but they did not seem to help me deal with this popup

[image]

`Handle Alert`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please refer this answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571119/loading-of-unpacked-extensions-is-disabled-by-the-administrator

Answer (score 3):

You can start browser using below method.

```
    ${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --start-maximized
    Call Method    ${options}    add_experimental_option  useAutomationExtension  ${False}
    Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
```

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. This really did solve my problem.

Comment: Awesome.. Thank you :)