# Failed to load extension from popup box while running selenium test cases in Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

> Failed to load extension from:
>   C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir18676_513995252\internal.
>   Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator.

I can't find a solution to prevent this pop-up each time I run test cases. Everything I've tried doesn't work and has been posted a two or more years ago. Yes this is something of a duplicate post but those solutions from 2+ years ago no longer work hence I'm asking again. This one is almost three years old discussing older versions of Chrome: [Older Post Regarding the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571119/loading-of-unpacked-extensions-is-disabled-by-the-administrator)

Working with Java Chrome version is 78.0.3904.87
Selenium version: 3.141.59

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);        
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.addArguments("disable-extensions");
```

This isn't part of the code now but I also tried this:

```
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[] {"enable-automation"});
```

Comment: Please show us more code. Especially what you are doing with `options`. The used Selenium version could also be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set all your chrome options before creating the ChromeDriver instance.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.addArguments("disable-extensions");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

---

BTW: I would recommend to use the [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) for handling the correct driver version.